# Android Jenkins CI with Auto-Restarting monkey testing

Tags: android, jenkins, monkeyrunner, monkey

I have an unused mac mini, so I installed Jenkins on it, and I'm trying to configure it so that it is always running monkey tests on our latest Android build. I can't find a way to do that though. I've found the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=57181910) which allows for the booting of an emulator and then running a Monkey Test on the build, but it only seems to be configurable for a certain number of events, not time based.

The ideal Jenkins configuration would poll a git server. When it sees a new commit on a specific branch, it would build the APK, run the emulator, and then start the monkey test. I'm sure crashes would happen, and every time a crash happens the test should restart. It should continue running like this indefinitely. Then when a new commit is detected, it would shut down the emulator, and start the build all over again.

Are there any creative ways that a Jenkins build could be configured to continually run monkey tests?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty standard use of Jenkins - use the Git SCM plugin to poll the repo where your Android build is made from, and run the tests if changes are found.  I'm less clear why you'd want to restart the tests if they fail - isn't that Einstein's definition of insanity, repeating the same actions and expecting a different result ?